# Is it possible to add a column with specific value to data in azure data factory pipeline

Tags: azure, logging, metadata, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I am copying data from system X to a blob storage as parquet file or excel file is it possible to add one more step that can help me add one more column with the pipeline run ID or Trigger ID?

Thank you in Advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you extracting the data from? If its a database, it is easy because you can add it in the sql statement used when selecting data. For example:

```
select *, NewColumn='Value' from yourTable
```

If you want a solution for every data source possible, you can use the derived column transformation in data flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column

Also you can add data from the pipeline itself using string functions, for example:

```
@concat('select *, pipeId= ''', pipeline().RunId,''' from SalesLT.Address')
```

This will select all the fields, and an additional field called pipeId which will have the same value for every row, and will be the pipeline run id.

Hope this helped!!

Comment: I am extracting from an azure SQL but the column I want to add is pipeline execution Id and trigger ID. Is it possible to add them with the query. In addition to that I cant use data flow in this process I need to do it with data copy if possible.
thanks for your reply I will try the query method that you suggested.

Comment: Hey just updated my answer to include the pipeline run id as an example