# Include dynamic property as source column in ADFv2 copy activity within foreach

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Copy activity with an OData endpoint as the source, and an Azure SQL Database table as the sink.

This copy activity is within a Foreach activity, with the items coming from another table. I am using the items iterated through the `foreach`, within the URL as a query parameter with `@item().Name` (where Name is the column of the item that I need).

Now, the sink of the copy activity has an extra column `Name` in which I want to write the current `@item().Name` in each record being copied. So for all records retrieved for endpoint with `Name=X` I want to populate the `Name` with `X`, etc.

However, when I am in the Copy Activity mapping, I cannot find any way to include the current item along with the other columns coming from the OData feed.

Is there a way to populate one column of the sink from an activity variable and the rest of the columns from the source data?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way will be inserting the data first into a database, then you could use something as explained here: [Is it possible to add a column with specific value to data in azure data factory pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57007733/is-it-possible-to-add-a-column-with-specific-value-to-data-in-azure-data-factory/57008208) where you end up using a select statement to add the new column.

If you dont, you may try using one of the functions within data flow. Then you can add @item().name as a variable and join/merge the original data with this new column.

Hope this helped!!

Comment: I ended up using a similar solution. I left the foreach sequential and the column I needed `null`, and then used a stored procedure to update all `null` values in the staging table to `@item().name`. Not pretty but works.